# Rails 3 ajax call - ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make an ajax call but I don't want to return any data, or perhaps only return a 200.

My error is

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template ....
```

My ajax method in the controller is...

```
# Ajax
def updatePlayStat()
    #do something
    render :layout => false
end
```

Is there a way to tell rails to return nothing, without creating an extra template file?

BTW i am making the ajax call by using jquery's `$.post` method in a js file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can render nothing with:

```
render :nothing => true
```

See:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 6):

first of all, please use ruby style syntax and write your methods in snake_case!

if you just want to return a status 200, you can use the `head` method in your controller: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Head/head

Comment: I'm +1ing for snake case, still working the java programming out of my system :) This is also a correct answer, just can't select 2.